# Navigate to one specific Item from one group with LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using a long list selector in a WP8 application.
The items are grouped alphabetically.

When I'm navigating to this page, sometimes I want the list to be scrolled to one specific item from one group.
I tried the function ScrollTo(), but this can take me only to one specific group from the list.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to achieve that.

To explain it better to you i would need to know how you have the groups organized.
I'll post here a sample that I hope can help you.

```
longListSelector.ScrollTo(((AlphaKeyGroup<Object>)longListSelector.ItemsSource[x])[y]);
```

Where **x** is the group index, and **y** is the item index inside the group